# How to get figure(n)?

Tags: r, plot

In matplotlib or matlab you can do something like:

```
figure(n)
clf()
```

How do we do this in R?

The desired action is to bring up a new blank plotting window in window "n" i.e. n=3. All subsequent plotting commands will appear in this active window.

I've definitely figured this out before but I always have to look it up when I come back to R. 
 I think "x11" plus some option might be the trick.

Comment: I don't know. Not everyone knows matplotlib or matlab. What do those commands do?

Comment: dev.set allows switching but is there really no command to just switch to the given device, making it exist if it does not exist?

Comment: Calling dev.new() before each plot seems to be mostly correct. Somehow R resets the figure numbering each time you source a file.

Comment: At the bottom of the help for `?x11` there are references to functions like `bringToTop` - is this what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple graphics devices open then `dev.list` will show a list of the open devices. The `dev.cur` function returns which of those is the current/active device.  You can use `dev.set` to choose which of the open devices to make the current or active device (where new plots will go to).  You could also use `dev.next` and `dev.prev` along with `dev.set` to cycle through the active devices.  You can look at the names of the return values from these functions to see what kinds of devices they are, this may help to rotate through screen devices while skipping file devices.

If you are in a mulptiple figure setup (`par(mfrow=c(3,2))`) within a single device, then you can use `par(mfg=c(r,c))` to set the figure in the r'th row and c'th column as the next figure to be plotted into.

Comment: Thanks. I forget how complicated R is for doing simple graphics. I think you still can not call dev.set when the device doesn't exist. You have to write your own function to do dev.new if not in dev.list or something like that.

Comment: @mathtick, did you try it?  I just typed `dev.set()` with no current graphics devices opened and it opened a new one for me.

Comment: Not really. dev.set() opens "Device 2" but then successive dev.set() or dev.set(3) do nothing. As a naive user, I would expect there to be one command to open a window, optionally specifying the device number.

Comment: @mathtick the `dev.new` function will open a new window (but does not take a device number).  It would not be hard to write a function that would check the current `dev.list` and does a `dev.set` if the number passed in is in the list and a `dev.new` otherwise.  I don't know what it should do if the specified number is something like 10 when the current list only has 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: I think the behaviour in matplotlib, matlab and octave is that "figure(n)" creates figure n if necessary and makes it the active window.